# Swift - Multiple UI changes block one-another

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, keyboard

It's been a real pain this issue!
I want to change the height of 2 elements, in a keyboard event, but as long as the one is a `UICollectionView`, it just refuses to do it!

If I comment the one out, the other will change normally, but together, it never works!

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    inputContainerView.frame.size.height = 81
    chatCollectionView.frame.size.height = 199
}
```

I've observed that the same thing happens, every time I want to update a `UICollectionView`'s frame, as long with some other's UI element and a keyboard event is involved. (I also tried it when a `UIKeyboardDidShow` notification is being posted, but the same issue occurs)

I've tried to run that block of code inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async`, but it doesn't help!

Does anyone has any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Use autolayout rather than setting frames directly. What if an external keyboard is being used? Do you still want to change the sizes if there is no onscreen keyboard?

Comment: @Paulw11 Unfortunately I didn't have the opportunity to sit and learn autolayout! Since I don't have the time to do it now, what else can I do?

Comment: You could try changing the frames in a `UIView` animation block (you should animate the changes anyway, since it will give a better user experience).  The symptoms you are describing sound like you are using auto layout since changing the frame of an object will trigger autolayout and affect the frames of other items.  How did you create your UI?  Programatically or with storyboard?  As per the answer and my previous comment; **use autolayout**  You will waste more time trying to make your UI work properly on multiple devices than you will spend setting it up with constraints.

Comment: You should also perform the animation in the keyboard notification, that way you can animate the changes alongside the keyboard appearance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using autolayout , so hook the height constraint for each one and

```
self.inputContainerViewHeight.constant = 81

self.chatCollectionViewHeight.constant = 199

self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Also animate it if you want

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5 , animations: {

  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have the opportunity to sit and learn autolayout! Since I don't have the time to do it now, what else can I do?

Comment: @SotirisKaniras Learn Autolayout, it was released 6 years ago. Building apps without Autolayout is strongly advised against and adjusting the frames of views should only be done by platform experts in the most specific of use cases.